# Is there any good "cube grid" component for Java / Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I need to represent quite some data for which a cube grid would just make perfect sense.  Does such a thing exist for Swing?

A "cube grid" looks like this (and it's *really* darn impressive):

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#cube_analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try JIDE Pivot table. I think it is pretty close to what you need.

More info at http://www.jidesoft.com/products/pivot.htm

Comment: +1 nice, it's indeed the kind of component I'm after :)

Answer (score 1):

Try out the free and simple Java swing component https://github.com/aristsoft/jpivot to visualize the data in multidimentional view.
It designed just to show the data, so it don't doing the data aggregation any kind itself.